# node.js sorting object (mongoose, express, ejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, object, ejs

i have this problem sorting my object of data in my index of my blog app.
I have a blog app based on Express using ejs and mongoDB using mongoose.
What i want is sorting the results so the newest post starts at the top. At this moment it will show the first post at the top.

app.js / mongoose schema

```
blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  image: String,
  body: String,
  created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
var Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);
```

app.js / Index route

```
app.get("/blogs", (req, res)=>{
  Blog.find({}, (err, blogs)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log("Error!");
      console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("index", {blogs: blogs});
    }
  });
});
```

index.ejs foreach

```
<% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
  <img alt="img" src="<%= blog.image %>">
  <a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>"><%= blog.title %></a>
  <span><%= blog.created.toDateString() %></span>
  <p><%- blog.body.substring(0, 200) %>...</p>
  <a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>">Read More</a>
<% }) %>
```

Does anyone have a clue how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort()` method of *Mongoose*:

```
Blog.find((err, blogs) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    res.render("index", { blogs: blogs });
  }
}).sort({ created: 'desc' });
```

Comment: Okey, that was amazing. So simple but yet i was far away!
Thank you alot!